# Can't find file when trying to open via command line.

Tags: windows, cmd

I wonder if someone can help, I want to run a schedule task and I discovered that I can put a command line command in there, which is good.

What I need to happen is for a PHP file to run a bit like a cronjob.

The system I am using recommends I do the below but it's not working, now I believe it's due to the file being on E and not C, but I have no idea how to correct this, if anyone could give me some pointers that would be great.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe E:\pathtofile\tasks\frequently.php -f"
```

System info is win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your quote characters all fouled up, but there are separate entries for the various parts of the command in Task Scheduler.

Try this:

When creating the new task, set the `Action:` dropdown to `Start a program`.

In the  `Program/Script:` entry, use

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe"
```

In the `Add arguments (optional)` entry use

```
"E:\pathtofile\tasks\frequently.php" -f
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to know is how to schedule the php program to process a php file via command prompt (Note that the -f needs to come immediately **after** the php.exe:

```
schtasks /Create /tn MyJob /tr @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe -f E:\pathtofile\tasks\frequently.php" /sc onlogon
```